# Most elegant way of ssh copying a file to a remote host, then executing it

Tags: ssh, vim

I find myself performing this REPL-like action quite often:

```
vim foo.sh
scp foo.sh host:/tmp/foo.sh
ssh host /tmp/foo.sh
# realizing it wasn't quite right
vim foo.sh
scp foo.sh host:/tmp/foo.sh
ssh host /tmp/foo.sh
# repeat many times
```

I was about to plow away at writing a shell script to make this simpler, but was wondering if someone smarter than me solved this problem more elegantly.

What's your solution?  Besides emacs :)

EDIT: Why not just edit my file on the remote host?  Simple, the hosts receiving my scripts won't always have a dev environment set up, so in this case host might not have all of my vim customizations; sometimes it'll be C code instead of a shell script, which means my workflow looks like:

```
vim foo.c
make
scp foo host:/tmp/foo
ssh host /tmp/foo
# repeat
```

That's why.  I guess I want something with an interface like:

```
edit_loop foo.c --make --copy-and-run=host:/tmp/foo
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

```
ssh remotehost bash < foo.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Mount your remote host as a local folder using SSH-FUSE.

Step 2: `vim ssh-mount/foo.sh`

Step 3: From a second terminal, or forking from vim, run `ssh host:.../foo.sh`

Rinse and repeat.

**Link**: http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

Comment: In fact, if you can run make with local tools, then you can use SSH-FUSE as in the C example, keep the source remote-mounted, and use local build tools.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to repeatedly `scp` to the server; let Vim handle that for you automatically!

> `vim scp://user@host/path/to/file`

You can then run `ssh user@host` in a separate terminal, and run `make` or `/path/to/file` there.

If you need a build environment that is not available on the server, you should instead check out the previous answer about `sshfs`.